# High range outdoors router?

Tags: router, ethernet, 4g

I have a [MikroTik SXT LTE6](https://mikrotik.com/product/sxt_lte6_kit) kit which I need a router for, to extend range. The reason being is because the place where I need the actual wifi coverage to be might/will be out of my LTE access point's range.

I would need about a 100 meters of range radius, but a super high-tech router with immeasurable speeds is also gratuitous as it would only be limited by the SXT. I'm not sure if there is a weatherproof option, but it definitely would be a plus, as there could be times, where it needs to be used outside.

Should a traditional router be enough or I need something specific? Could you recommend a brand or type?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would suggest running an ethernet cable from the LTE access point to the place where you need the wifi signal and add the router there.  While you may be able to find a router with a 100-meter range, at that length the speeds will be extremely slow.  [This cable should be long enough](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07648BCNV).  It is also weatherproof.